# Setting up a server on a Mac Mini with OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac, webserver, osx-server

I'm in the process of setting up my Mac Mini as a home server. For that reason I seek some guidance:

- I want to have a "Fileserver" meaning 2 different user accounts with read/write permissions to 1 specific folder each. Meaning that they have to be "chrooted" to that folder. Do I use ftp, ssh? Should I create the users like regular users on the Mac Mini or?
- I want to have a customizeable webserver which i can install php, mysql, phpmyadmin, django etc. Should I use the buildt in webserver? MAMP? XAMP?
- I want to be able to mount my fileserver on my other macs.

What are the best approaches for these 2 problems? Tips and tricks are highly appreciated!

PS: I also got the "server" app for Lion.. Though it seems quite waste of money for my use :)

Comment: What are your clients gonna be?

Comment: @slhck: Myself. I do want to be able to connect remotely. And I want it to be somehow secure.

Comment: No, I mean, Windows laptops or Mac Pros or a Linux machine, et cetera.

Comment: @slhck: Hmm you thinking of using afp? It should support Windows/Linux/Solaris etc.. So I would prefer ftp/ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of environment are you trying to setup ? a dev env? a production one ?
if it's a dev ENV, MAMP will do great but it's a production server you should consider installing macport and then deploy apache and the modules you need to run your web sites (i.e. mod_python mod_php) you can find proper instructions for a clean web server install [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP)